# LoRa Ra-02 SX1278 and the ESP32 WROOM

Tags: esp32, micropython

I am using the ESP32 WROOM as well as a single LoRa Ra-02 SX1278. Now I have made a burglar alarm with micropython and what I really want is to send a text message to my mobile phone via the Lora module when the alarm goes off. I've been looking for examples in micropython for a while but can't really find anything. My question is can you send a message via bluetooth with a single LoRa Ra-02 SX1278 module and the ESP32 WROOM.

Comment: **1)lora and bluetooth are different things** so you can't send bluetooth messages via lora **2) smartphones are not equipped with lora hardware** so you can't send messages via lora directly to the smartphone. **3) esp32 can send bluetooth messages to the smartphone** without external lora module

Comment: Wow, this question is a ... confusion of technologies.